# .htaccess redirect attempt redirects wrong domain to wrong url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I went and broke my .htaccess somehow. I admit that .htaccess is not something I usually mess around with, but I thought if I followed other examples, I'd manage it.

Originally I was trying to redirect [www.shadowlordscomics.com](http://www.shadowlordscomics.com) to a new drupal site in a subfolder. But I left off the s at the end of comics, which broke the url. However, instead of redirecting [www.shadowlordscomics.com](http://www.shadowlordscomics.com) to the broken url, it redirected a different domain that uses the same space, [officialshadowlords.com](http://officialshadowlords.com).

The .htaccess file originally only had this inside of it:

```
Options -Indexes
```

What I used for my redirect was based off of this:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.mysite.com/   [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^$ drupal/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/drupal%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule .* drupal/$0 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* drupal/index.php?q=$0 [QSA]
```

Is there a way to revert the redirect? To make it stop redirecting to the broken url? *Officialshadowlords.com* is meant to be going to an *index.html* file in its sub-folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can redirect to home page using errordocument
ERRORDOCUMENT 404 /